# Why is one List returning 26 items and another returning 1?

Tags: c#, list, linq, enumeration

```cs
var result = new List<QuickSearchModel>();
var Navmenus = CommonConstants.GetNavItems();
var items = new List<NavMenuItem>();
Navmenus.ForEach(it =>
{
    if (it.IsNested)
    {
        it.menuItems.ForEach(mi => items.Add(new NavMenuItem() { Name = it.Name + "/" + mi.Name, Link = mi.Link }));
    }
    else { 
        items.Add(new NavMenuItem() { Name = it.Name, Link = it.Link });
        result.Add(new QuickSearchModel() { Id = "1", Title = it.Name, ItemType = it.Name, Route = it.Link });
    }
});
return result;
```

At the end of my code block when I am returning my results, I am expecting 26 items.
In my immediate window, i type **items** and I see 26 NavMenuItems listed
when I type **result**, i see 1 QuickSearchModel listed (the 3rd in my items list)

Please see these two images as reference

[image]
[image]

SOLUTION:

I ultimately did this

```
    public static List<QuickSearchModel> PageListFromNavMenu()
    {            
        var Navmenus = CommonConstants.GetNavItems();
        var items = new List<NavMenuItem>();
        Navmenus.ForEach(it =>
        {
            if (it.IsNested)
            {
                it.menuItems.ForEach(mi => items.Add(new NavMenuItem() { Name = it.Name + "/" + mi.Name, Link = mi.Link }));
            }
            else { 
                items.Add(new NavMenuItem() { Name = it.Name, Link = it.Link });                    
            }
        });            
        return PageListFromNavMenu(items);
    }
    private static List<QuickSearchModel> PageListFromNavMenu(List<NavMenuItem> items)
    {
        var result = new List<QuickSearchModel>();
        items.ForEach(it =>
        {
            result.Add(new QuickSearchModel() { Id="1", Title = it.Name, ItemType = it.Name, Route = it.Link });
        });
        return result;
    }
```

It's a shame that I had to run through a 2nd For Loop to get the results but it did work. I wish I could have just have done it in the else block.

Comment: because "else" is executed once and "it.menuItems.ForEach in if" 25 times(or rather (Navmenus.Count - 1) * (it.menuItems.Count) gave 25)?

Comment: the else block is executed 25 times. Thats the block of code I'm interested in. It is a good observation. I did add 2 images for reference.

Comment: You are only returning the `result` list. the `items` list is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a list of NavMenuItems just to convert it to a list of QuickSearchModels? Create QuickSearchModels in your first method (and never create an intermediate `List<NavMenuItem>`)

```cs
public static List<QuickSearchModel> PageListFromNavMenu()
{            
    var Navmenus = CommonConstants.GetNavItems();
    var items = new List<QuickSearchModel>();
    Navmenus.ForEach(it =>
    {
        if (it.IsNested)
        {
            foreach (var mi in it.menuItems) {
                string name = it.Name + "/" + mi.Name;
                items.Add(new QuickSearchModel {
                    Id = "1",
                    Title = name,
                    ItemType = name,
                    Link = mi.Link
                });
            }
        }
        else { 
            items.Add(new QuickSearchModel {
                Id = "1",
                Title = it.Name,
                ItemType = it.Name,
                Link = it.Link
            });
        }
    });            
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Because the code says so. If the NavMenu-item is nested, add something to items colletion, otherwise add it to items and result collection. Obviously you have one root element and 25 child items.

Comment: I added an image. Please see the image. It should have the same number if items as the items. Right?

Comment: Put breakpoint inside the IF block, put breakpoint inside the ELSE block. Count how many times you hit each.

Comment: I did. I hit it 25 times.

Comment: Yes sir. I hit the else block 25 times.  I only have 3 top level menu and several items in my menu. One of my menu has 25 items in it.

Comment: Do a quick test. Insert `int a = 0, b = 0;` before the ForEach. in the `if` add `a++;` in the `else` add `b++;`. Then you will see exactly how many times the two parts are executed. Lambdas are tricky to debug. Sometimes it is just better to use a good old `foreach` loop instead of a `ForEach` extension method.

Comment: Exactly, the issue here must come from the ForEach extension method, try foreach(var it in Navmenus) { ... }